# Laravel Eloquent querying pivot table not unique

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For some reason I don't get the expected result when doing the following:

```
$cars = Car::query();
$cars->whereIsVisible(true);

# output: $list 
// [2016-01-16 09:30:04] local.INFO: array (
//   0 => 5,
//   1 => 7,
//   2 => 9,
//   3 => 3,
// )  

$cars->whereHas('specifications', function($query) use ($list) {
    $query->whereIn('id', ($list)); 
});

$cars->get();
```

What I expect is that I get only cars that have all the specifications that are inside that $list, but that's not correct. Even when I fill in more specifications, I get a bigger result. So there goes something wrong.

I'm used to Eloquent, so I suck in queries. But this is the Query:

```
select * from "cars" where "cars"."deleted_at" is null 
and "is_visible" = true 
and (select count(*) 
from "specs" inner join "car_specs" 
on "specs"."id" = "car_specs"."facility_id" 
where "car_specs"."car_id" = "cars"."id" 
and "id" in (5, 7, 9 ,3)) >= 1
```

Anyone see where it goes wrong? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

`whereHas` just checks that you have cars with the provided specifications, not that it returns those cars that match your specifications.

I think you should use `where` directly.